# What is the proper kanji for "King's/Conqueror's will" or "spirit" vertically?

Tags: translation

覇王色の覇気 < this  Literal translation means Haki of the Color of the Conquering King.

I am looking for the proper vertical translations of

Conquering King
Conqueror's Will/Spirit
Will/Spirit of a Conqueror
King's Will/Spirit
Will/Spirit of a King

Comment: What do you mean by "vertical" translation?

Comment: *Vertical* is the opposite of *lateral*, not the opposite of *literal*.

Comment: and what is a lateral translation??

Comment: Please don't tattoo this...

Comment: @istrasci Are you saying this because you're getting the feeling these questions are going to result in some sort of terrible tattoo art somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Because "覇王色の覇気" is a concrete phrase in the actual Japanese story, I understand and answer your question where you want to get an appropriate interpretation in English for the phrase.

My answer for **覇王色の覇気** is:

> ### Will/Spirit of King's/Conqueror's aura.

If you really looking for the proper vertical translations of
- Conquering King
- Conqueror's Will/Spirit
- Will/Spirit of a Conqueror
- King's Will/Spirit
- Will/Spirit of a King

> They are **覇王** for the first one and **覇王の覇気** for the rest.

I'm sorry to say but there are no other options.

The meanings of individual words in the dictionary are as follows. The italic is my poor translation.

[覇者｛はしゃ｝](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E8%A6%87%E8%80%85-114245#E3.83.87.E3.82.B8.E3.82.BF.E3.83.AB.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.B3.89)
<デジタル大辞泉>
１ 徳によらず、覇道（武力や策略）によって天下を治める者。
*Those who rule the world by arms and/or strategies, not by virtue*.

[色｛いろ｝](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E8%89%B2-32548)
<デジタル大辞泉>
４
㋑それらしく感じられる趣・気配。「秋の色の感じられる昨今」「敗北の色が濃い」
*Feelings or signs that seem like someone/something*.

[覇気｛はき｝](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E8%A6%87%E6%B0%97-599919#E3.83.87.E3.82.B8.E3.82.BF.E3.83.AB.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.B3.89)
<デジタル大辞泉>
２ 人の上に立とうとする強い意志。野心。野望。
*Strong will or ambition to stand on people*.

<大辞林第三版>
⓶ 覇者になろうという気持ち。人に勝ってのし上がろうとする野望。野心。
*Will to be a "覇者 conqueror". Ambition to overcome opponents and try to stand on them*.